# Mail merge HTML email in gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, html-email, mailmerge

Is it possible to mail merge HTML emails using gmail?

I want to send HTML emails for professional looks and insert the recipent's name for greater impact. Ideally I would like to avoid using mailchimp or another online platform for this task.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: It is possible.  Check the options object in GmailApp.sendEmail()

Comment: There's services like GMass too

Comment: Is [this](https://developers.google.com/workspace/solutions/mail-merge) what you were looking for?